# Error on retrieving data from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

My app is always crashing at launch. My code is based on retrieving data from firebase realtime database and putting the values in the textviews. then on button click it will compare answer that the user put and the real answer and check if they match. maybe my code is getting ruined by the finals the android studio put because it will be error if I dont put finals. Maybe the error is in the part of retriving data from firebase because its my first time in android studio doing this.

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView questionText;
    TextInputEditText answerText;
    TextView hintText;
    Button button;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    String question;
    String hint;
    String answer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        questionText = findViewById(R.id.question);
        hintText = findViewById(R.id.hint);
        answerText = findViewById(R.id.input_answer);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final setClass setClass = new setClass();
        final int cnt = 1;

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                // whenever data at this location is updated.

                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot0 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    dataSnapshot0.getValue(com.example.quizremastered.setClass.class);

                    setClass.SetQuestion(dataSnapshot0.child(String.valueOf(cnt)).getValue(com.example.quizremastered.setClass.class).GetQuestion());
                    setClass.SetHint(dataSnapshot0.child(String.valueOf(cnt)).getValue(com.example.quizremastered.setClass.class).GetHint());
                    setClass.SetAnswer(dataSnapshot0.child(String.valueOf(cnt)).getValue(com.example.quizremastered.setClass.class).GetAnswer());

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }


        });

        questionText.setText(setClass.GetQuestion());
        hintText.setText(setClass.GetHint());

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String answerInput = answerText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
                if (answerInput.isEmpty()) {
                    answerText.setError("Field can't be empty");
                } else {
                    answerText.setError(null);
                    if (answerInput == setClass.GetAnswer()) {
                        button.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);
                    }
                    //else
                    {
                        button.setBackgroundColor(GREEN);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

setClass.java:

```
package com.example.quizremastered;

public class setClass {
    private String question;
    private String hint;
    private String answer;

    public setClass(){
    }

    public String GetQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public String GetHint() {
        return hint;
    }

    public String GetAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void SetQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public void SetHint(String hint) {
        this.hint = hint;
    }

    public void SetAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/question"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Question:"
            android:layout_marginTop="100sp"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:text="Hint:"
            android:layout_below="@id/question"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_answer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/hint"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="20"
            app:errorEnabled="true">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Answer"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:text="Answer"
    android:layout_below="@id/input_answer"
/>
```

Comment: Initialised **myRef** in your code.

Comment: Can you explain it?

Comment: myRef =database.getReference(); like this...

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.  Please also responde with @AlexMamo